# Cannot step into code at breakpoints in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, debugging, webstorm

I write some JavaScript code in WebStorm. I can't step into code at breakpoints at line 3, but I can do this at line 10.

[image]

I expect to be able to step into code at both breakpoints.

Comment: Just to clarify: Your screenshot shows that the debugger stopped at line #3. So now you want to **step into** the Node.js **core library** `fs.readFileSync()` function? I'm not using Node.js so cannot check this, but will `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Stepping | JavaScript | Do not step into library scripts` make any difference?